# How to prove a map between two spaces of real sequences $f : l^1 \to l^2 $ is well-defined and continuous

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

the question is whether the following statement is ture or false, and justify it.
Here is the statement

> The map $f : l^1\to l^2$ given by 
>     $f(x_0, x_1, x_2,...)= (x_0, x_1, x_2,...) $ is well-defined and continuous.

[Recall that:

- $l^1$ is  the space of real sequences $(x_n)$ such that $\sum_0^\infty|x_n|$ converges with norm $||(x_n)||_1 =\sum_0^\infty|x_n|$.
- $l^2$ is  the space of real sequences $(x_n)$ such that $\sum_0^\infty x_n^2$ converges with norm $||(x_n)||_1 =\sqrt{\sum_0^\infty x_n^2}$.]

[topological properties of standard metric spaces may be quoted without proof]

I know to prove well-defined is to prove something like $f(a)=f(b)$ then $a=b$. am I correct?

Also, I am little confused about proving continuity of this real sequences map. Could someone please give me some hints on this? (does it related to homeomorphism)
 Thanks a lot.

Comment: $f(a) = f(b) \Rightarrow a = b$ is for proving injectivity (i.e. function is one-to-one). Instead, well-defined means that the functions "makes sense". It means that for every member in the domain the rule provided works (so there will be an unambiguous output and the output must be in the co-domain)

Comment: thank you for clarifying! @KelvinSoh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that $f$ is well-defined, you want to show that if you pick $(x_n) \in l^1$, then $f\big((x_n) \big) \in l^2$, that is, the map actually does what it says it will do in terms of mapping an element from its domain to it's codomain.

**Theorem**: Suppose $1\le p_1<p_2\le\infty.$ Prove that $\ell^{p_1}\subseteq \ell^{p_2}$ by proving that $\|a\|_{p_2}\le\|a\|_{p_1}$ for any $a\in \ell^{p_1}.$

**Proof**: Define $b_n := \frac{a_n}{\|a\|_{p_1}}$ and observe that $\vert b_n \vert \leq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Notice the following chain of equivalent statements:
                    $$\begin{align*}
      \vert b_n \vert^{p_2} &\leq \vert b_n \vert^{p_1} \\
      \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \vert b_n \vert^{p_2} & \leq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \vert b_n \vert^{p_1} \\
      \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \bigg \vert \frac{a_n}{\|a\|_{p_1}} \bigg \vert^{p_2} & \leq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \bigg \vert \frac{a_n}{\|a\|_{p_1}} \bigg \vert^{p_1} \\
      \Bigg(\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \bigg \vert \frac{a_n}{\|a\|_{p_1}} \bigg \vert^{p_2}\Bigg)^{1/p_1} & \leq \Bigg( \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \bigg \vert \frac{a_n}{\|a\|_{p_1}} \bigg \vert^{p_1} \Bigg)^{1/p_1}\\
      \frac{1}{\big(\|a\|_{p_1}\big)^{p_2/p_1}} \Bigg(\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \vert a_n \vert^{p_2} \Bigg)^{1/p_1} & \leq 1\\
      \Bigg(\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \vert a_n \vert^{p_2} \Bigg)^{1/p_1} & \leq \big(\|a\|_{p_1}\big)^{p_2/p_1}\\
      \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \vert a_n \vert^{p_2}  & \leq \big(\|a\|_{p_1}\big)^{p_2}\\
      \Bigg(\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \vert a_n \vert^{p_2} \Bigg)^{1/p_2} & \leq \|a\|_{p_1}\\
       \|a\|_{p_2}& \leq \|a\|_{p_1}.
     \end{align*}$$

Consider the case when $p_2 = \infty$, notice that $\vert a_n \vert \leq \bigg(\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \vert a_n \vert^{p_1} \bigg)^{1/p_1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, and thus $\|a_n\|_{p_2} = \|a_n\|_\infty = \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \vert a_n \vert \leq \bigg(\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \vert a_n \vert^{p_1} \bigg)^{1/p_1} = \|a_n\|_{p_1}$. $\square$

By applying this theorem to $p_1 = 1$ and $p_2 = 2$, we get that $f$ is well-defined.

To show that $f$ is continuous, let $\varepsilon > 0$, then if $\|(x_n) - (y_n) \|_1 < \delta = \varepsilon$, again by the second part of the theorem, we get that $\|f\big( (x_n)\big) - f\big((y_n) \big) \|_2 = \|(x_n) - (y_n)\|_2 \leq \|(x_n) - (y_n)\|_1 < \varepsilon$. Conclude by definition that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: How can we prove that it is not compact?